# How do i pass multiple variables to writing ODBC function?

Tags: asterisk

I need to insert some data to SQL ftom Asterisk dialplan. I am using ODBC connection and func_odbc.conf file. There are good way to READ several values from SQl, but apparently, i can't find any working solution for inserting several variables to func_odbc function.

I already tried to use NoOp(ODBC_FunctionName(${ARG1},${ARG2},${ARG3})) and it does not work with 'writesql'. Set(${ODBC_Function()={${ARG1},${ARG2},${ARG3}}) is not working either due to Set limited for one name/value pair.

Here is my func_odbc:

```
[putClientEvaluation]
;${ARG1} - uniqueid
;${ARG2} - operator
;${ARG3} - client
;${ARG4} - rating
;${ARG5} - queue
dsn=voip
writesql=INSERT INTO cc_service_rating(timestamp,callid,operator,client,rating,queue) values(now(),'${SQL_ESC(${ARG1})}','${SQL_ESC(${ARG2})}','${SQL_ESC(${ARG3})}','${SQL_ESC(${ARG4})}','${SQL_ESC(${ARG5})}')
```

So i need a working way to pass several arguments at once to odbc writesql function.

UPDATE:

Looks like i just have to use VAL instead of ARG:

```
writesql=INSERT INTO cc_service_rating(timestamp,callid,operator,client,rating,queue) values(now(),'${SQL_ESC(${VAL1})}','${SQL_ESC(${VAL2})}','${SQL_ESC(${VAL3})}','${SQL_ESC(${VAL4})}','${SQL_ESC(${VAL5})}')
```

But i still get warning from Set:

```
WARNING[1227][C-00000020]: pbx_variables.c:1155 pbx_builtin_setvar: Set requires one variable name/value pair.
```

So, how do i do this without using Set?

UPD:

Did this, no warnings now:

macro extension

```
exten => s,n,Set(operator=${ARG1})
exten => s,n,Set(quename=${ARG2})
exten => s,n,Set(client=${ARG3})
;timestamp,callid,operator,client,rating,queue
exten => s,n,Set(ODBC_putClientEvaluation()=${UNIQUEID},${operator},${client},${MACRO_EXTEN},${quename})
```

function

```
writesql=INSERT INTO cc_service_rating(timestamp,callid,operator,client,rating,queue) values(now(),'${VAL1}','${ARG1}','${ARG3}','${VAL2}','${ARG3}')
```

Not shure why does this work, obviousely i don't understand how ARG and VAL works here, and why putting args in function brackets does not work at all (even with comma screening).

Answer (score 0):

You are using variables incorrect. Please read book article about variables.

```
Set(ODBC_Function(${ARG1},${ARG2})=${VAL1},"fixed_param",${VAL3})
```

Comment: What book article do you suggest?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try like this:

Set(ODBC_Function()=${VAR1},"fixed_param",${VAL3});